# Keep Button :focus when changing Tabs in TabPane

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I currently have two menus. One a tabPane and the other a VBox of buttons. Using the psuedo selector I can have the tabs change CSS when selected. Here's one example.

```
.tab.log {
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/log.png");

}
.tab.log:selected {
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/logActive.png");
}
```

I can reach a similiar functionality with the buttons with this CSS:

```
.battleButton {
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/battle.png");=
}

.battleButton:focused{
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/battleActive.png");=
}
```

The problem with this is changing tabs takes away the :focus from the buttons - how can stop this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Before i say "you cant" i would like to ask, why you want to have a different background image on Button when it is focused? Maybe you want something like ToggleButton?

Comment: If the button is unselected it's background image is a little dull (50% opacity) -> when clicked it's 100%. It's a little UI enhancement to help the user know where in the application they are. ToggleButton looks like it might work I'll have a look.

Comment: I am pretty sure that ToggleButton is what you are looking for then. Also keep in mind that you can group many ToggleButtons with ToggleGroup, more info https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/toggle-button.htm

Comment: I agree, thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with ToggleButtons sharing a ToggleGroup.